# Skeleton image and text in adjacent columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm a CSS beginner having a problem with Skeleton when the browser is resized. I have an image and text next to each other in columns as shown below (except much more text than shown below). This works fine, but when you reisze the browser to make it narrower, the text overlaps the image for a sizeable distance before it "snaps" below the image when you get to a very narrow browser width.

I think there's some way to fix this using the Skeleton CSS Utilities, but I haven't been able to figure out how. My understanding of CSS is very basic.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="one-third column">
        <img src="images/myimage.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="two-thirds column">
        Lots of latin text here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any css to post?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following class to the image: u-max-full-width, like this:

```
<img class="u-max-full-width" src="images/myimage.jpg" />
```